# Javascript Module Pattern doesn't give correct instanceof

Tags: javascript, instanceof

Sometimes you think you know something, and then it turns out you really don't...

I've been doing a lot of research into the Javascript inheritance over the last few days for a talk I'm giving at a local tech group.  No problem I figured, I know this stuff, I'll just brush up...

Turns out, I've lots still to learn.  Here is the first thing that surprised me:

```
function Vehicle() {
   function move() {
      console.log('moving');
   }
   return {move: move}
}

function OtherVehicle() {
   this.alsoMove = function() {
      console.log('also moving')
   }
}
```

The first method is what I've always understood the module pattern to be.  The second, though I don't know it's name, I understood to be basically equivalent - just a minor syntactic variation.

Except:

```
(new Vehicle()) instanceof Vehicle \\ returns false
(new OtherVehicle()) instanceof OtherVehicle \\ returns true
```

`new Vehicle()` returns an 'Object'.
Looking at this, that makes sense, but it was not what I was expecting.
Can anyone explain what is going on here, why, and maybe point me at a really good resource that gets into the guts of this?

As a follow-up.

```
var Car = function() { 
   function drive() { console.log('driving') };
   return {drive: drive}
}

Car.prototype = new Vehicle() //I know, Object.create preferred

(new Car).move() //undefined

// However...
var Car = function() { 
   this.drive = function () { console.log('driving') };
}

Car.prototype = new Vehicle();
(new Car()).move() //output 'moving'
```

So, the module pattern can't be used in inheritance?
Or have I just woken from the wrong side of the bed today and should go for a run before I next touch a keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any particularly good [resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), but here's some feedback anyway.

> new Vehicle() returns an 'Object'.

The `return {}`, overrides the default return value `this`, which *is* the instantiated object. Calling such functions with `new` is pointless as `this` gets discarded. As far as OOP languages go, JavaScript is a bit odd in that it allows you to return another value for `this` in a constructor.

So yes, inheritance used that way won't work: `{}` itself is not in any way linked to a parent/base class, which is why

> (new Car).move() //undefined

is undefined.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes absolute sense.  Still feel like I've been doing it wrong all these years.  Still, composition over inheritance anyway, right? ;-)

Comment: You bet :-) (I'm a DI fan). I know what you mean - I'm still learning new things about JavaScript regularly after a couple of decades of using it (and I'm by no means an expert).. Especially now that NodeJS got popular, it's really taken off..